# Iphone 5 stuck on 1,xxx,xxx,xxx seconds to unlock

Tags: ios, iphone

My Iphone 5 is stuck on X,xxx,xxx,xxx seconds to unlock, I done a hard reset (home + power for several seconds) but it doesn't doesn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: what do u mean by X,xxx,xxx,xxx seconds ? Did you get this after enetering a wrong password multiple times?

Comment: Can you take a picture of what you are seeing and upload it separately?  Do you remember what version of iOS you are running on the phone?

Comment: @enzo I think so...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you entered wrong password/passcode many times resulting to a lockdown. You'll need to restore your iPhone using iTunes. Internet connection is needed.

1. Open iTunes
2. Connect the iPhone to the computer
3. Turn off your iPhone then hold the Home button + Power button. The phone should go in the recovery mode (iTunes logo).
4. On iTunes, follow the on-screen instructions.

For more details on the procedure read [If you forgot the passcode for your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or your device is disabled](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306) on Apple's support site, especially the chapter titled [Erase your device with recovery mode to remove your passcode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306#recovery).

Comment: doesn't work says password needs to be entered (

Comment: before it can connect to itunes

Comment: You missed the step 3. Try again

Comment: sorry didnt work

Comment: it still says iPhone is disabled

Comment: You have to connect the cable first then power off the phone. Afterwards power on the phone holding home button. Should display iTunes logo then the restore process should start on iTunes.

Comment: sorry didnt work

Comment: Seriously?! What are you doing to make it not working? The instructions are simple.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Do you have Find My iPhone enabled?

Comment: I don't know my friend gave me this phone.

Comment: I'll prob have to take it to apple store (

Comment: So ask them about that. If Find My iPhone is enabled and you perform a  restore, you will stick at the activation screen and thus forever.

Comment: ok, what does my friend need to do if it is enabled? he was stuck on that screen too

Comment: He simply needs to disable it from his iCloud account then restore the phone.

Comment: he has a new phone, i dont really want to bother him, is it seperate for each phone?

Comment: Just ask him to! Or if I'm not wrong, this is a stolen iPhone and you try to use it. I won't help you further.

Comment: ok i'll ask, the thinh is he is using a new iphone, will he still have access to the old iphone in his icloud?

Comment: If he didn't create a new one yes! Just ask him to delete data on the iPhone he gave to you (remotely)